# Remove an internal element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Hello good people im improvising with jQuery and i want to remove an internal element, a child element without removing its content.
 This is my code:

```
<li class="homepage">
  <a class="megamenu" href="#" id="megamenu_27">
    <span class="nodesc">        
        <span class="title"> Home </span>
    </span>
</a>
```

`jQuery("li.homepage").find("a").remove("span");`

I just want to remove the spans element without removing the content: "Home"

like this:

```
<li class="homepage">

     <a class="megamenu" href="#" id="megamenu_27">

        Home

    </a>
```

Comment: Did you find my solution useful?

Comment: This is what i get when i use it, @DhruvJoshi : "TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Comment: See a working fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/rST9k/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try with:

```
jQuery("li.homepage").find("a").each(function(){
    var text = jQuery(this).find('.title').text();
    jQuery(this).find('span').remove();
    jQuery(this).text(text);
});
```

Comment: @Sergiti Remember to accept an answer you find the most helpful with the tick on the left.

Comment: Oh i didnt know it. Im kinda new here!

Answer (score 0):

This will retain your title span and remove `.nodesc`

`jQuery("li.homepage").find("span.title").unwrap();`

http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var temp = jQuery("li.homepage").find("a");
temp.html(temp.find("span").html());
```

[Or you can use jQuery unwarp()](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use unwrap()

```
$('.homepage a span').contents().unwrap();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HvcE2/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var e=  $("li.homepage");// stores the DOM element in variable to reuse
var t= e.find(".title").text();// filter element to get text and save it in a variable
  e.find("span").remove();// remove the span
  e.text(t);// add stored text to element
```

Comment: if there are more html elements inside, with your way just the text without the html elements will be taken: http://jsfiddle.net/rST9k/1/ as you can see, the html elements are lost!